# how to find whether one element is present in a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, vector

i have two 2d string vectors. how can i search for whether one element of one vector is present in the other vector or not? 
i have already tried using **find_if** and **any_of** but its not working.
thanks.
This is what i tried:

```
int main(){
    vector <vector<string>> reference_state_cell;
    vector <vector<string>> input_array;

    /* then i put necessary data inside those two 2d vectors*/

    for (int f = 0; f < 52; f++){
        for (int g = 0; g < 10; g++){
            if (any_of(reference_state_cell.begin(), reference_state_cell.end(), bind2nd(equal_to<string>(), input_array[f][g])))
            {
                cout << ",";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << input_array[f][g];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting with first principles. How would you change your code if you didn't have `any_of` available to you? You would loop over the first vector also in couple of nested `for` loops.

```
int main()
{   
   vector <vector <string>> reference_state_cell;
   vector < vector<string>> input_array;

   /* then i put necessary data inside those two 2d vectors*/

   for (int f=0;f<52;f++){
      for (int g=0;g<10;g++){

         bool found = false;
         for (size_t i = 0; i < reference_state_cell.size(); ++i )
         {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < reference_state_cell[i].size(); ++j )
            {
               if ( reference_state_cell[i][j] = input_array[f][g] )
               {
                  found = true;
                  break;
               }
            }
         }

         if ( found )
         {
            cout << ",";
         }
         else
         {
            cout<<input_array[f][g];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Once you get that to work, you can see how the innermost loop can be replaced by a call to `std::any_of`.

```
int main()
{
   vector <vector <string>> reference_state_cell;
   vector < vector<string>> input_array;

   /* then i put necessary data inside those two 2d vectors*/

   for (int f=0;f<52;f++){
      for (int g=0;g<10;g++){

         bool found = false;
         for (size_t i = 0; i < reference_state_cell.size(); ++i )
         {
            found = any_of(reference_state_cell[i].begin(),
                           reference_state_cell[i].end(),
                           [=](std::string const& item){return input_array[f][g] == item;});
            if ( found)
            {
               break;
            }
         }

         if ( found )
         {
            cout << ",";
         }
         else
         {
            cout<<input_array[f][g];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Once you get that working, you can think of replacing the now innermost loop with another `std::any_of`. Notice that you will need to use a lambda function and two `std::any_of` calls.

```
int main()
{
   vector <vector <string>> reference_state_cell;
   vector < vector<string>> input_array;

   /* then i put necessary data inside those two 2d vectors*/

   for (int f=0;f<52;f++){
      for (int g=0;g<10;g++){

         bool found = 
            any_of(reference_state_cell.begin(),
                   reference_state_cell.end(),
                   [=](vector<string> const& vs) { return any_of(vs.begin(),
                                                                 vs.end(),
                                                                 [=](std::string const& item){return input_array[f][g] == item;});
```

); })
             if ( found )
             {
                cout << ",";
             }
             else
             {
                cout<

If the vectors are large, and using two for loops (use of `std::any_of` hides the loops, it does not take them away) to search for each item is expensive, you may want to create a `std::set<std::string>` to improve performance.

```
int main()
{
   vector <vector <string>> reference_state_cell;
   vector < vector<string>> input_array;

   /* then i put necessary data inside those two 2d vectors*/

   // Construct a set of strings.
   std::set<std::string> stringSet;
   for ( auto const& vs : reference_state_cell)
      for ( auto const& item : vs )
         stringSet.insert(item);

   for (int f=0;f<52;f++){
      for (int g=0;g<10;g++){

         bool found = any_of(stringSet.begin(),
                             stringSet.end(),
                             [=](std::string const& item){return input_array[f][g] == item;});
         if ( found )
         {
            cout << ",";
         }
         else
         {
            cout<<input_array[f][g];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That really helped..Thanks a lot.@R Sahu

Comment: now if i want to know which cell of the reference_cell was found equal to which cell of the input_array. how can i return a pointer which carries the information about reference id and position of that cell so that i can go back to the original state? or is there any better way other than using pointer? thanks in advance@R Sahu

Comment: @Sandiproy, you can store that information in a `std::pair<size_t, size_t>`. Pointers will also work to get to the elements but they won't help you figure out the row and column. IMO, storing the indices in a pair is better.

Comment: when i am trying to use your example using 'std::set' it is giving me an error ': no match for call to ‘(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>) (const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’|' . any idea how to solve this issue? @R Sahu

Comment: @Sandiproy, that was an error on my part. It's fixed now.

Comment: @R Sahu yaa  it works fine now. but still cant figure out a way how can i use          'std::pair<size_t,size_t>'  to store all the information that which cell of the reference_cell were found equal to which cell of the input_array? because at the end i need to reverse the whole operation to get back the original data gain. i am really stuck at this position. thanks again

Comment: @Sandiproy, You need to store them in a `std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>>`.

Comment: @R Sahu (http://stackoverflow.com/q/44016493/7314454) please give me a solution for this if possible. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here "reference_state_cell"  is a 2D vector.  But in your code you never visit it in 2d way.

You May try...

```
any_of(reference_state_cell[index].begin(),reference_state_cell[index].end(),bind2nd(equal_to<string>(),input_array[f][g])))
```